# PHP/MySQL Form Values SUM with dropdown options

Tags: php, mysql

I need some guidance and excuse me that I'm not posting any samples of what I have but right now I'm blocked.

I have a database table with the following values to load the form values from.

**COLUMNS**

```
q_answer | ans_value
Yes      | 20
No       | 0
```

Now what I'm trying to accomplish is to create a form with 6 questions and next to each question a dropdown with the values Yes and No and below it a box that displays the value of the answer, meaning YES = 20 , NO = 0

After all the questions are answered, I need it to sum the value and echo it on a "Final Score" field but there is a condition. If the 6th question is answered "Yes", then the final score value should be 0, otherwise if the answer is NO, then the final score should be the sum of the value of the first 5 question.

I need the resulting value of each question to be stored in another DB table (form_results) with the columns, q1_score, q2_score, q3_score, q4_score, q5_score, q6_answer, final_score

I tried to do this using PHPRunner but have been unsuccessful which is why I'm not posting the code for the form I've been trying to use but any assistance with this, I can use it to implement it into my project.

Thank you,

UPDATE:

I been playing around with javascript to try and accomplish what I want and it's not the cleanest code but it's partially doing the trick. I just can't get to SUM the values if the 6th question is NO. all it does is to COUNT how many answered there are but not the actual SUM of the resulting values of each question and on top of that, it erased the resulting values when I choose "No" in the 6th question.

```js
var ctrlquestion_1 = Runner.getControl(pageid, 'question_1');
var ctrlquestion_2 = Runner.getControl(pageid, 'question_2');
var ctrlquestion_3 = Runner.getControl(pageid, 'question_3');
var ctrlquestion_4 = Runner.getControl(pageid, 'question_4');
var ctrlquestion_5 = Runner.getControl(pageid, 'question_5');
var ctrlquestion_6 = Runner.getControl(pageid, 'question_6');
var ctrlq1_score = Runner.getControl(pageid, 'q1_score');
var ctrlq2_score = Runner.getControl(pageid, 'q2_score');
var ctrlq3_score = Runner.getControl(pageid, 'q3_score');
var ctrlq4_score = Runner.getControl(pageid, 'q4_score');
var ctrlq5_score = Runner.getControl(pageid, 'q5_score');
var ctrlfinal_score = Runner.getControl(pageid, 'final_score');
 
ctrlquestion_1.on('change', function(e){
if (this.getValue() == 'Yes'){
ctrlq1_score.setValue(20);
}else{
ctrlq1_score.setValue(0);
}
}); 

ctrlquestion_2.on('change', function(e){
if (this.getValue() == 'Yes'){
ctrlq2_score.setValue(20);
}else{
ctrlq2_score.setValue(0);
}
}); 
ctrlquestion_3.on('change', function(e){
if (this.getValue() == 'Yes'){
ctrlq3_score.setValue(20);
}else{
ctrlq3_score.setValue(0);
}
}); 

ctrlquestion_4.on('change', function(e){
if (this.getValue() == 'Yes'){
ctrlq4_score.setValue(20);
}else{
ctrlq4_score.setValue(0);
}
}); 

ctrlquestion_5.on('change', function(e){
if (this.getValue() == 'Yes'){
ctrlq5_score.setValue(20);
}else{
ctrlq5_score.setValue(0);

}
}); 

ctrlquestion_6.on('change', function(e){
if (this.getValue() == 'Yes'){
ctrlfinal_score.setValue(0);
}else{
ctrlfinal_score.setValue(ctrlq1_score.setValue() + ctrlq2_score.setValue() + ctrlq3_score.setValue() + ctrlq4_score.setValue()+ ctrlq5_score.setValue());

}
});
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: I don't know what to post about the code because PHPRunner doesn't give me an actual PHP Code to work with, it only shows all processing variables.